# Вылеты из игры на всех телефонах Unity/Ui

Tags: c#, unity3d, gui, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Проблема заключается в том, что программа вылетает на всех телефонах при переходе в меню выбора уровня.Изначально меню неактивно и выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
При нажатии кнопки "Start" происходит следующее:

```
public Transform mMenu; //main menu
public Transform clMenu; //select level
public GameObject cv_lvl_icon; // Объект, который хранит ячейки уровней
private int LastCompletedLevel = 0;

public void Show_menu_change_lvl()
{
    LastCompletedLevel = 10; // Последний пройденный уровень

    for (int i = 1; i <= LastCompletedLevel; i++) // Проходим по всем иконкам (Panel)
    {
        cv_lvl_icon.transform.GetChild(i - 1).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = i.ToString(); //  Вписываем номер уровня
        cv_lvl_icon.transform.GetChild(i - 1).GetChild(0).GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false); // Убираем замочек
    }
    show_menu(mMenu, clMenu);
}
    public void show_menu(Transform fromMenu, Transform toMenu)
{
    fromMenu.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    toMenu.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Если например поставить LastCompletedLevel = 1 или 2, то код отрабатывает без проблем
Пробовал через корутины с ожиданием 2-10 секунд - все равно вылетает. Пробовал заменить SetActive на Destroy, тоже не помогло

### Иерархия:

### [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На Пк работает нормально, в итоге должно получится вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Вашем коде как минимум два узких места. Нет проверки, что `i` меньше числа дочерних объектов. И нет проверки на результат `GetChild(0)` и `GetComponent<Text>()`. Попробуйте так: `var title = cv_lvl_icon.transform.GetChild(i - 1)?.GetChild(0)?.GetComponent<Text>();
if (title != null) title.text = i.ToString();
var img = cv_lvl_icon.transform.GetChild(i - 1)?.GetChild(0)?.GetChild(0)?.gameObject;
if (img != null) img.SetActive(false);`

И посмотрите на телефоне, какие кнопки не будут обновляться. В тех и проблема.

Comment: Странно, открылся только 1 из 10, почему так могло произойти? Все панели одинаковые

Comment: Сделайте еще отображение в интерфейсе значения `LastCompletedLevel`.

Comment: В любом случае спасибо за ответ, действительно проблема была в строке cv_lvl_icon.transform.GetChild(i - 1).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = i.ToString(); Но почему так, я пока не в курсе :) Самое интересное чем ПК отличается от андроида, что на одном устройстве все работает, а на другом нет

Comment: Добавил 
        test1.GetComponent<Text>().text = LastCompletedLevel.ToString(); Теперь игра опять вылетает

Comment: Пора меня движок, это невозможно

Comment: Как и когда вызывается метод `Show_menu_change_lvl`? В **Awake**? Попробуйте в **Start** или **OnEnable**

Comment: Возможно, переменная LastCompletedLevel не инициализирована на момент цикла

Comment: Show_menu_change_lvl вызывается по нажатию кнопки Begin game, после чего открывается это меню. Сделал все как было с проверкой на null, теперь игра стала вылетать :D Магия

Comment: Массив отрабатывает, вылетает из-за функции  show_menu(mMenu, clMenu); Но в ней кроме SetActive ничего нет

Comment: Значит убедитесь, что передаваемые в `show_menu` аргументы не равны null. Перезагрузите сцену и убедитесь, что в сохраненной сцене всем ссылкам в скриптах назначены объекты.

Comment: Я так сразу сделал if(mMenu!= null && clMenu!= null) show_menu(mMenu, clMenu); Всем ссылкам назначены объекты, может мне перейти на юнити 2018? А то у меня последняя 2019

Comment: Без этой строчки var title = cv_lvl_icon.transform.GetChild(i - 1)?.GetChild(0)?.GetComponent<Text>(); if (title != null) title.text = i.ToString(); тоже все работает нормально

Comment: Причем если итерация проходит 1-2 раза - все работает идеально. Начиная с 3 итерации вылетает, я скоро застрелюсь

Comment: Добавил Show_menu_change_lvl(); в старт, запускается идеально и открывает все 15 уровней, а если функцию запустить по нажатию кнопки, то выкидывает

Comment: В общем если заменить cv_lvl_icon.transform.GetChild(i - 1)?.GetChild(0)?.GetComponent<Text>(); if (title != null) title.text = i.ToString(); на cv_lvl_icon.transform.GetChild(i - 1)?.GetChild(0)?.GetComponent<Text>(); if (title != null) title.text = "Что угодно"; то работает, но почему - никто не знает. Корутины тоже не помогли